# ¿Cómo regresar a una aplicación Android después de ser redirigido al navegador?

Tags: android, apache, cordova

Estoy programando una aplicación en Android con ayuda de Apache Cordova, el detalle es que cuando una api me redirige a un sitio web del navegador fuera de la app no tengo como regresar a la aplicación.

Por ejemplo, en mi api hecha en C# yo le paso esta dirección y me funciona cuando hago test en el navegador .

```
request.RedirectUrl = "http://localhost:8000/pedidos.html";
```

Pero cuando compilo la app no funciona esa redirección porque ya no estoy en el navegador.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi con un plugin de cordova que se llama inappbrowser